# Convert string to title case after dash or slash

Tags: javascript, string, capitalization, capitalize

I use this common function to convert most of my list items to title case with no issues.  I've discovered one place that needs improvement, when there is a dash or slash in the middle, I want the next letter capitalized.

For example Hispanic/latino should be Hispanic/Latino.  Basically capitalize when the first letter or proceeded by a symbol OR a space.

Current code:

```
function toTitleCase(str) {
    return str.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|\s)\w/g, function (match) {
        return match.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just change your capture of whitespace `\s`, to be a class of characters being whitespace, a hyphen or a slash `[\s-/]` (and anything else you want)

```js
function toTitleCase(str) {
    return str.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|[\s-/])\w/g, function (match) {
        return match.toUpperCase();
    });
}

console.log(toTitleCase("test here"));
console.log(toTitleCase("test/here"));
console.log(toTitleCase("test-here"));
```

Answer (score 3):

just add or conditions in regex `/(?:^|\s|\/|\-)\w/g`

```js
function toTitleCase(str) {
    return str.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|\s|\/|\-)\w/g, function (match) { 
      return match.toUpperCase();  
    });
}


console.log(toTitleCase('His/her new text-book'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that strips the dashes. So for the following input:

```
list-item
```

It returns:

```
ListItem
```

An extension of Jamiec's solution that will achieve this is:

```js
function toTitleCase(str) {
    return str.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|[\s-/])\w/g, function (match) {
        return match.toUpperCase();
    }).replace('-', '');
}
console.log(toTitleCase("list-item"));
```